# Create an interactive stacked plot similar to ggplot2

Tags: r, rcharts, ggvis, googlevis

I am designing a stacked plot in R in order to add it to a shiny app but I would like to create the plot with interactive elements. First, I would describe the plot. I have a matrix `Data` that looks like this (I add the `dput()` version in the final side):

```
     A1   A2   B1  B2  C1
A1 2000 1500 1000 500 500
A2    0  100  100 200 400
B1    0    0   50 200 300
B2    0    0    0 100 200
C1    0    0    0   0 100
```

In order to build the stacked plot I do some operations with `Data`:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
#Melting data
Melt.Data<-melt(Data)
Melt.Data<-transform(Melt.Data, Var1 = factor(Var1, colnames(Data)),
                      Var2 = factor(Var2, rownames(Data)))
Melt.Data$Var2=substring(Melt.Data$Var2,1,1)
#Plot
Plot=ggplot(Melt.Data, aes(x = Var1, y = value, fill = Var2)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + scale_y_continuous(labels = comma) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = rainbow(3))  
plot(Plot)
```

After running this code I got the next graphic. The goal of this graphic is show the evolution of 3 groups (A,B,C) across different stages (A1,A2,B1,B2,C1). So, it is better showed in a stacked plot.
[image]

The logic used by `ggplot2` is helpful because it shows the evolution around the stages. I have tried to replicate the same plot with interactive functions from packages, such as, `googleVis`, `rcharts`, `rHighcharts` and `ggvis`, but I can't get the same result. Also, some functions from this packages can't show the evolution.

I would like to build a similar graphic with interactive elements in order to get a better aspect for a shiny app. The `dput()` version of `Data` is the next:

```
Data<-structure(c(2000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1500, 100, 0, 0, 0, 1000, 100, 
50, 0, 0, 500, 200, 200, 100, 0, 500, 400, 300, 200, 100), .Dim = c(5L, 
5L), .Dimnames = list(c("A1", "A2", "B1", "B2", "C1"), c("A1", 
"A2", "B1", "B2", "C1")))
```

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: I have no idea what do you mean by "interactive elements", but I thought it could be helpful to show you a simpler way of creating the same plot without `ggplot2` (no legend), using `dplyr` instead of `plyr`: `data2 <- data.frame(data) %>% mutate(A=A1+A2, B=B1+B2, C=C1) %>% select(A, B, C) %>% t` to plot: `barplot(data2, col=rainbow(3))`.

Comment: Dear @Molx interactive elements for example when you touch a zone of the graphic, it shows values. Something like this: http://glimmer.rstudio.com/reinholdsson/rHighcharts/ section barchart I tried with `Data` in this style but it is not the same result.

Comment: When looking into it, I found the Bioconductor package SVGAnnotation, which is able to do that, but couldn't get it to work with a barplot either. http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/extra/html/SVGAnnotation.html